# View values in htmltable/grid not being redrawn with new values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I pass a view using GET and a html table with an anchor in table cell is drawn.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult myViewer()
    {
        DateTime myDte = DateTime.Now;
        if (TempData.ContainsKey("myDteVal")) { myDte = Convert.ToDateTime(   TempData["myDteVal"]); }
        myViewModel model = new myViewModel();
        List<DateTime> dtGridTimes = Utilities.GetTimesWithInterval(myDte, TimeSpan.Parse("06:00"), TimeSpan.Parse("18:00"));
        model.GridDateTimes = dtGridTimes;
        return View(model);
      }
```

Here is the view part that renders the grid.

```
   <tr>
   @foreach (var q in Model.GridDateTimes)
   {
     DateTime myDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(q.Text);
     <td class="viewerCols"><a href="@Url.Action("Booking", "Common", new {  lnkDateTime =   @myDateTime.ToString() })">   <span>&nbsp;</span></a></td>
    }
  </tr>
```

I then change the date using my calendar control and post the changed value and successfully collect it in the post controller action.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyViewer(string dateValue)
    {
        TempData["myDteVal"] = dateValue;
        return RedirectToAction("myViewer");            
    }
```

Once again the GET is utilised to redraw the grid/html table. I pass between GET & POST using viewData. So the parameter lnkData in my Url.action should now store the new date when I right click, inspect element. It keeps the initial data no matter how many times I change.

I wondered if anyone had any idea of where I am missing the point. I have thoroughly tried to work it out. My knowledge here has let me down here.

Comment: Have you debugged it to see what's happening to `TempData["myDteVal"]`?

Comment: I even debug in the view. So set a break point right at the last part of the view rendering where the anchor parameter is filled with the date. It even says the new date as far as I can go. When it displays it still holds the old datevalue.

Comment: Is the calendar control a javascript popup calendar?

Comment: Its Bootstrapper calender control. I do this  $('.input-group.date').datepicker().on('changeDate', function (ev) {
                var url = "/Common/MyViewer";
                var myDate = $('#dteTester').val();
                    $.post(url, { dateValue: myDate }, function (data) {
                        //alert(data);
                    });
                });

Comment: So I came out of the table structure and just did this. <h3>@Model.GridDateTimes.First().Text</h3>  The data always stays the same. The new view changes are not being reflected. Somehow.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're redirecting from the `HttpPost` version of MyViewer to the `HttpGet` version, It's just over-complicating things. Instead of redirecting, you can build the model and return to the View directly, that way you don't need to use `TempData`

Comment: I did that first of all and had this problem. So the RedirectToAction was to try to solve this problem. I will put it back and take out the ViewData. The problem still remains. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: ok, so in the 2nd comment you said that you debugged it and saw that the date was correct? so `q.Text` is the new date?

Comment: q.Text is the new date. I have removed the tables completely. So I just do this now. <h3>
        @Model.GridDateTimes.First().Text
        @{
            int myNum = 1 + 2;
        }
    </h3> int myNum is where I put my breakpoint. So I look in GridDateTime first element and it says the new date I selected. Just doesn't reflect in the browser.

Comment: When you build the url, you don't need `@` in front of `@myDateTime.ToString()` - I don't know if that would cause the problem but it's worth a try

Comment: This works. $.post(url, { dateValue: myDate }, function (data) {
                        
                        $("#mainBody").html(data);
                    }); So the returned view gets passed to the caller. I then push it out. So I need to make this partial ajax. What a learning curve. Thanks for all your advice and time mark. I'm missing bit's of understanding. Slowly getting there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.post(url, { dateValue: myDate }, function (data) { $("#mainBody").html(data); });
```